# Mockery method shouldRecieve() is not found on this mock object

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-4, mockery

I'm using the padraic/mockery package with Laravel and PHPunit. I'm on PHP 5.4.3.

When trying to create a mock object to test a controller I receive an error:

```
"BadMethodCallException: Method ... shouldRecieve() is not found on this mock object"
```

My code is below, I'm following a tutorial pretty closely but can't work out why my mocked object doesn't appear to be instantiating properly.

```
public function testItWorks()
{
    $mocked = m::mock('SearchRepositoryInterface');
    App::instance('SearchRepositoryInterface', $mocked);

    $mocked->shouldRecieve('test')->once()->andReturn('NOT hitting the db');
    $response = $this->call('GET', 'search');

    $this->assertTrue($response->isOK());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo.
It is `shouldReceive` instead of `shouldRecieve`

Comment: Damn! I spent hours trying to work out what was going on here. I'd just about given up on Mockery! It's always something small...Thanks though, good spot!

Comment: i before e except after c